# Interpretation of split point in getTree(randomForest) for factor when split point is 0

Tags: r, random-forest

How to interpret `spli_point` in `getTree(randomForest)` when the value of split for factor is 0 ? Here is the picture, look at row 11:

**Picture:**
[image]

Comment: Give some toy code to make the problem. If I can see the problem myself then I can probably attack it more effectively.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't make any sense to me.
To figure things out, I suggest to change the factor-levels and then compare the result.

Ok, then you could also prepare some test-data and track how it is classified by this tree. Set this factor-level one time to 0 and then copy the row and set it to 1. Then take a look if this changes the classification.
However this should be easy for a decision-tree ... I'm not sure how to track this in a forest.

Comment: That "0" for factors occurs in many cases which I have tried.

Answer (score 0):

It's a leaf node; there is no split variable (as designated by `<NA>`) because no split is done at the leaf node.  You can tell this various ways; from the `<NA>`, from the fact that it has no daughter nodes (daughter nodes $= 0$), and from the `status = -1` values.